# Can two different medications in the same bottle contaminate one another.

Tags: urine, test

Last week, I went to my pain control doctor, I came up positive for an opiate I do not take. The gal who works for me, asks Me all the time if sheshe can put her pills in my pill bottle. We do manual labor, it’s impossible to carry a purse with you.  Is it possible, that my pills could’ve got tainted with hers? The doctor said it was a very very small dosage, I never thought about it, is it possible?

Comment: Not really, but can you keep them apart is the real question here.

Comment: @Narusan I would agree if they're capsules or coated tablets, but uncoated tablets do shed some dust. It's possible enough of that dust got on Sandie's pills to show up positive on a drug test.

Comment: Also it is illegal to carry a controlled substance that is not yours, you are running a huge risk - you can get arrested and convicted, in some places it's a felony.  She should carry them in her own prescription bottle in a pocket or fanny pack or whatever she has to do.